# My items in my listView are not aligning properly?

Tags: java, android, listview, text, alignment

rather than explain what's happening, [here](http://i1320.photobucket.com/albums/u531/highlandbuck/Screenshot_2013-08-06-10-11-412_zpsb963dfec.png)'s a screen-grab:

As you can see my item list is aaaalll over the shop. Going to paste both activity_main.xml and another one that formats the list, list_row.xml

ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#121212">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/logo" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/main_title"
android:textColor="#33b5e5"
android:background="#1f1f1f"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="14sp"/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:background="#121212"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:dividerHeight="2dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

LIST_ROW.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:background="#121212">
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:background="#121212">
<TableRow>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:padding="2dip"
android:background="#121212"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/description"
android:padding="2dip"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:singleLine="true"
android:background="#121212"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving weights to ImageView and TextView like android:layout_weight as the ratio you want. 
And dont forget to make android:layout_width = "match_parent" otherwise weights will have no effect..

Answer (score 0):

remove the `Table layout`

and use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#121212"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#121212"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:src="@drawable/instructions" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#121212"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="tomer"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked, although the list is now left-aligned. Was hoping for center alignment but this will do.